# Navigation bar prompt & height resize animation

Tags: ios, animation, height, uinavigationbar, prompt

Good day!

I have an embedded navigation bar in my app. 
mainView is a ViewController with tableView in it.
On first launch there is no prompt text on navigation bar. When you get to options (second view controller) you can set a text to your main views prompt. So after you do so, returning from "Options" to mainView triggers nice and smooth animation on navigation bar increasing its height and prompt text appears.

When i launch the app for the second time, where prompt text is loaded, the text is ok, the size is ok, but the animations of height resize start to get glitchy when switching views, navigation bar height jumps from big to small w/o animation, although text appears to dissolve as usual.

Here is an example of where i switch views in a loaded app:

[image: Middle of transition, black square is a background during the height jump from small to big]

If i go to options view controller and again set the prompt text -> animation of height increase between views gets fine.

I'm sure i am missing something at launch, something like tableView.reloadData() in viewDidLoad, but for navigation bar.